# Nested data types in postgresql-simple

Tags: haskell, postgresql-simple

Consider following code which can find some set of coordinates:

```
data Coord = Coord { lat :: Float
                   , lon :: Float
                   }

instance FromRow Coord where
  fromRow = Coord
    <$> field
    <*> field

findSomePoints :: Connection -> Int -> IO [Coord]
findSomePoints = undefined
```

Then I would like to define data type for named set of coordinates:

```
data Path = Path { name :: String
                 , points :: [Coord]
                 }

instance FromRow Path where
  fromRow = Path
    <$> field
    <*> -- PROBLEM: would like to call something like `findSomePoints conn field` here...

findPath :: Connection -> Int -> IO Path
findPath = undefined
```

Unfortunatelly, I don't know how to compose data types with queries (in my case `Path` with `Coord`). Is something like this even possible (and how?).

Comment: What's the SQL query equivalent of your `findPath`?  Is there an SQL column with the SQL type `coord[]`, or something shaped more like `(String, Float, Float)`?

Comment: @bergey: Coordinates and paths are defined in different tables. There exists many-to-many relationship between them.

Comment: Exactly.  If the data exists in different tables then it makes little sense to create a `FromRow` instance since the data is not in one row.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Then, how can I create a `Path` data type when the data are logically tied together? Should I have something like `CoordRow` and `PathRow` data types which I then turn into `Path` data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write a data type and a `FromRow` instance for each table in the database, and separate the database code from the changing-schema code.  `PathRow` and `[Coord]` are things you can get directly from the DB.  `makePath :: PathRow -> [Coord] -> Path`, to build the nested structure you want, doesn't need to interact with the database at all.  Then `findPath` can be implemented in terms of these pieces.